# Is it possible to dual boot with Windows 7 encrypted with True Crypt and Linux Mint?

Tags: windows-7, linux-mint, truecrypt, disk-encryption

I wish I knew if this scenario is possible:

- Windows 7 Installation 1 (Encrypted) (Real)
- Windows 7 Installation 2 (Hidden Volume) (Fake)
- Linux Mint 16 "Petra"

If you can not in the above manner, then how would the process to maintain Dual Boot Windows 7 and Linux Mint.

Comment: It should be possible.  Have you [this documentation](http://grub.enbug.org/TrueCrypt)

Comment: Link does not open